# SharePoint site collection not allowing to perform any actions

Tags: 2013, site-collection, error

I am facing issues with my SharePoint site collection. Whenever I try to perform any actions like, creating List or Library or modifying views or updating any document it throws error. But in back-end it performs whatever change I made.

For Example I created list but it throw error:

```
Sorry, something went wrong 

Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904 

Technical Details
```

But it created the list in the site but when I try to open the list it throws error `404 Not Found`.

When I try to modify the list view by adding a column or removing the column it throws below error:

```
Error 

Cannot complete this action.

Please try again.
```

But when I open that list again, that column is added/removed.

> This issue happens only on one site collection, my other site
>   collections are working fine.

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE:**
ULS Error logs:

```
09/19/2018 09:50:14.84  w3wp.exe (0x17D0)                           0x1354  SharePoint Foundation           Database                        ahjqp   High        [Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 09/19/2018 09:50:14.81, Original Level: Verbose] SQL connection time: 0.0646730240854634 for Data Source=WSS-SQL2012;Initial Catalog=SP_ContentDB5;Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=False;Enlist=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;Asynchronous Processing=False;Connection Reset=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Replication=False;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;Load Balance Timeout=0;Packet Size=8000;Type System Version=Latest;Application Name=".Net SqlClient Data Provider";User Instance=False;Context Connection=False;Transaction Binding="Implicit Unbind";ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False 5544909e-ba0e-406e-69ff-289769aad599


09/19/2018 09:50:14.99  w3wp.exe (0x17D0)                           0x1354  SharePoint Foundation           Database                        ahjqp   High        [Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 09/19/2018 09:50:14.88, Original Level: Verbose] SQL connection time: 0.0449079422105323 for Data Source=WSS-SQL2012;Initial Catalog=SP_ContentDB5;Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=False;Enlist=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;Asynchronous Processing=False;Connection Reset=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Replication=False;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;Load Balance Timeout=0;Packet Size=8000;Type System Version=Latest;Application Name=".Net SqlClient Data Provider";User Instance=False;Context Connection=False;Transaction Binding="Implicit Unbind";ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False 5544909e-ba0e-406e-69ff-289769aad599


09/19/2018 09:50:15.15  w3wp.exe (0x17D0)                           0x1354  SharePoint Foundation           Database                        ahjqp   High        [Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 09/19/2018 09:50:14.99, Original Level: Verbose] SQL connection time: 0.0245142888272113 for Data Source=WSS-SQL2012;Initial Catalog=SP_ContentDB5;Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=False;Enlist=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;Asynchronous Processing=False;Connection Reset=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Replication=False;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;Load Balance Timeout=0;Packet Size=8000;Type System Version=Latest;Application Name=".Net SqlClient Data Provider";User Instance=False;Context Connection=False;Transaction Binding="Implicit Unbind";ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False 5544909e-ba0e-406e-69ff-289769aad599




09/19/2018 10:34:17.33  w3wp.exe (0x17D0)                           0x2A28  SharePoint Foundation           Database                        ahjqp   High        [Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 09/19/2018 10:34:16.94, Original Level: Verbose] SQL connection time: 0.0254222254504413 for Data Source=WSS-SQL2012;Initial Catalog=SP_ContentDB5;Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=False;Enlist=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;Asynchronous Processing=False;Connection Reset=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Replication=False;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;Load Balance Timeout=0;Packet Size=8000;Type System Version=Latest;Application Name=".Net SqlClient Data Provider";User Instance=False;Context Connection=False;Transaction Binding="Implicit Unbind";ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False da46909e-ea1c-406e-69ff-2c29da502b3b



09/19/2018 10:34:17.33  w3wp.exe (0x17D0)                           0x2A28  SharePoint Foundation           Database                        880i    High        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'EventCache_Id'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.EventCache'. The duplicate key value is (13670245, a458d368-93cd-4d00-aba7-affdc041dbd2).  Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'EventCache_Id'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.EventCache'. The duplicate key value is (13670246, a458d368-93cd-4d00-aba7-affdc041dbd2).  Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'EventCache_Id'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.EventCache'. The duplicate key value is (13670247, a458d368-93cd-4d00-aba7-affdc041dbd2).  Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'EventCache_Id'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.EventCache'. The duplicate key value is (13670248, a458d368-93cd-4d00-aba7-affdc041dbd2).  Vio... da46909e-ea1c-406e-69ff-2c29da502b3b

09/19/2018 10:34:17.33* w3wp.exe (0x17D0)                           0x2A28  SharePoint Foundation           Database                        880i    High        ...lation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'EventCache_Id'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.EventCache'. The duplicate key value is (13670249, a458d368-93cd-4d00-aba7-affdc041dbd2).  The statement has been terminated.  The statement has been terminated.  Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.  The statement has been terminated.  The statement has been terminated.  The statement has been terminated.     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdH...  da46909e-ea1c-406e-69ff-2c29da502b3b

09/19/2018 10:34:17.33* w3wp.exe (0x17D0)                           0x2A28  SharePoint Foundation           Database                        880i    High        ...andler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncW...  da46909e-ea1c-406e-69ff-2c29da502b3b

09/19/2018 10:34:17.33* w3wp.exe (0x17D0)                           0x2A28  SharePoint Foundation           Database                        880i    High        ...rite)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior, SqlQueryData monitoringData, Boolean retryForDeadLock)  ClientConnectionId:c5ed73bf-c3bd-495d-b198-99d9a4040d89    da46909e-ea1c-406e-69ff-2c29da502b3b

09/19/2018 10:34:17.33  w3wp.exe (0x17D0)                           0x2A28  SharePoint Foundation           Database                        880k    High           at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.ExecuteQueryInternal(Boolean retryfordeadlock)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.ExecuteQuery(Boolean retryfordeadlock)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.CreateListFromFormPost(String bstrUrl, String& pbstrGuid, String& pbstrNextUrl)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.CreateListFromFormPost(String bstrUrl, String& pbstrGuid, String& pbstrNextUrl)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.CreateListFromFormPost(String bstrUrl, String& pbstrGuid, String& pbstrNextUrl)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListCollection.CreateListFromRpc(NameValueCollection queryString, Uri& nextUrl)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.NewListPage.BtnOk_Click(Object sender, EventArgs args)     at System.Web.UI.... da46909e-ea1c-406e-69ff-2c29da502b3b

09/19/2018 10:34:17.33* w3wp.exe (0x17D0)                           0x2A28  SharePoint Foundation           Database                        880k    High        ...WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback ...  da46909e-ea1c-406e-69ff-2c29da502b3b

09/19/2018 10:34:17.33* w3wp.exe (0x17D0)                           0x2A28  SharePoint Foundation           Database                        880k    High        ...cb)     at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, Int...  da46909e-ea1c-406e-69ff-2c29da502b3b

09/19/2018 10:34:17.33  w3wp.exe (0x17D0)                           0x2A28  SharePoint Foundation           Database                        880j    High        SqlError: 'Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'EventCache_Id'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.EventCache'. The duplicate key value is (13670245, a458d368-93cd-4d00-aba7-affdc041dbd2).'    Source: '.Net SqlClient Data Provider' Number: 2627 State: 1 Class: 14 Procedure: 'proc_LogChange' LineNumber: 39 Server: 'WSS-SQL2012'    da46909e-ea1c-406e-69ff-2c29da502b3b

09/19/2018 10:34:17.33  w3wp.exe (0x17D0)                           0x2A28  SharePoint Foundation           Database                        880j    High        SqlError: 'Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'EventCache_Id'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.EventCache'. The duplicate key value is (13670246, a458d368-93cd-4d00-aba7-affdc041dbd2).'    Source: '.Net SqlClient Data Provider' Number: 2627 State: 1 Class: 14 Procedure: 'proc_LogContentTypeChange' LineNumber: 48 Server: 'WSS-SQL2012' da46909e-ea1c-406e-69ff-2c29da502b3b

09/19/2018 10:34:17.33  w3wp.exe (0x17D0)                           0x2A28  SharePoint Foundation           Database                        880j    High        SqlError: 'Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'EventCache_Id'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.EventCache'. The duplicate key value is (13670247, a458d368-93cd-4d00-aba7-affdc041dbd2).'    Source: '.Net SqlClient Data Provider' Number: 2627 State: 1 Class: 14 Procedure: 'proc_LogChange' LineNumber: 39 Server: 'WSS-SQL2012'    da46909e-ea1c-406e-69ff-2c29da502b3b

09/19/2018 10:34:17.33  w3wp.exe (0x17D0)                           0x2A28  SharePoint Foundation           Database                        880j    High        SqlError: 'Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'EventCache_Id'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.EventCache'. The duplicate key value is (13670248, a458d368-93cd-4d00-aba7-affdc041dbd2).'    Source: '.Net SqlClient Data Provider' Number: 2627 State: 1 Class: 14 Procedure: 'proc_LogContentTypeChange' LineNumber: 48 Server: 'WSS-SQL2012' da46909e-ea1c-406e-69ff-2c29da502b3b
```

**I am facing issues in one site collection, none of operations works in the site like add/update/delete/creation of list/library/site.**

Answer (score 2):

**Some points to check**

- If the site collection hosted in an independent content database, make sure that the content database not in `Read-Only` mode.
- Also, make sure that the database not in a [Single User Mode](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/05/30/database-not-accessible-error-because-single-user-mode-for-content-database-in-sharepoint-2010/).
- Make sure that the `Site Quota` is not set!
- Make sure the database hard disk is not `FULL`.
- Try to repair your site collection using [Repair-SPSite](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/repair-spsite?view=sharepoint-ps) cmdlet that detects the issues and try to fix it automatically.

Comment: Thank you sir for the response. We checked database is not read-only as other site collection which are using same content database are not affected. Site Quota is also not set, Hard disk having around 1TB free space. We tried to backup and restore site using PS. But it throw an error.

Answer (score 2):

According to logs the issue was with the Duplicate keys created under few lists/tables in SQL Content DB of site collection which prevents all operations in the site.

**Resolution:** The list/tables names will be found in ULS logs.

> Fortunately those tables are history/events cache in our case.

We took the database backup and removed all the duplicate rows from the Database table in SQL Server.

[image: SQL Script to remove duplicate IDs]

Also [this article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/vinitt/2010/01/01/how-to-clear-event-cache-table-in-supportable-ways/) is helpful to understand this issue further.

Comment: Great! Glad to find a solution for your issue, thanks for sharing it on SE :)

Answer (score 0):

If you expand the technical details on the error page, there should be a guid (big string of letters and numbers). If you have access to the server, find the ULS logs and do a search in the log for that guid. There should be a more detailed error message of what's going on.

While the logs are just text files, finding the logs can actually be a little challenging, as your farm could have multiple servers. The default location is \Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\LOGS\, but that can be configured in central admin. Though if you need to do this more often then check into the uls log viewer tool from microsoft, or use [powershell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/view-diagnostic-logs).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have updated my question. Please check the error logs.